# Apache Ignite CollisionSpi configuration

Tags: performance, cluster-computing, load-balancing, ignite, gridgain

I have a requirement like "Only allow cache updates on same cache to run in sequence". Our client node is written in .net.

Every cache has affinity key and we use computeJob.AffinityCallAsync("cacheName", "affinityKey", job) to submit the compute job for execution.

Now If I use collisionSpi then, can I achieve "Sync jobs running on same node for same cache"? What configuration do I need to use?

Do I need to write same configuration for all the nodes(server and client)? I saw collisionSpi has no implementation for .net, so what can I do for .net client node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your job logic in a `lock` to make it run in sequence:

```
public class MyJob : IComputeFunc<string>
{
    private static readonly object SyncRoot = new object();

    public string Invoke()
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            // Update cache
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- `ICache.Invoke` may be a better fit for your use case
- The requirement for sequential update sounds weird and may cause suboptimal performance: Ignite caches are safe to update concurrently. Please make sure this requirement makes sense.

**UPDATE**

Adding a lock will ensure that one update happens at a time **on a given node**. Other nodes may perform updates in parallel. The order of updates is not guaranteed as well.

Comment: Thanks Pavel. I have a question like either I need to go with lock or ICache.Invoke right? If I will use lock condition then it will run jobs sequentially for a cache. So, when another cache's update request will run simultaneously. is that correct?

Comment: Would you please suggest, how to test this scenario on local and on dev server?

Comment: @Jigna `ICache.Invoke` is an alternative to `AffinityCall` which may or may not be better depending on the use case. Lock is required in both of them if we need to satisfy "Only allow cache updates on same cache to run in sequence" requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much. I implemented this solution and it's working fine. I tested without lock, and with lock. But, I am not able to find out much difference. Would you please suggest how to test this lock scenario on Ignite?